# GridBagLayout is in the center of BoxLayout instead of being on the top

Tags: java, swing

The sample below describes the following app:

Button that is on the NORTH of the BorderLayout, adds GridBagLayout panel with some components to the BoxLayout.Y_AXIS that is inside BorderLayout.CENTER. But after clicking the button, panel appears in the center, instead of being added to the top.

```
public class Test extends JFrame {
    public Test() {
        super("Test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JButton add = new JButton("Add");
        add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                panel.add(new RecordPanel("text1", "text2"));
                panel.revalidate();
            }
        });

        Container container = getContentPane();
        container.add(add, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        container.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setSize(300, 500);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    private class RecordPanel extends JPanel {
        private JRadioButton radioButton;
        private JLabel textLabel1;
        private JLabel textLabel2;

        public RecordPanel(String text1, String text2) {
            super();
            radioButton = new JRadioButton();
            textLabel1 = new JLabel(text1);
            textLabel2 = new JLabel(text2);
            initGUI();
        }

        private void initGUI() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

            constraints.gridx = 0;
            constraints.gridy = 0;
            add(radioButton, constraints);

            constraints.gridx = 1;
            constraints.gridy = 0;
            constraints.weightx = 1.0;
            constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            add(textLabel1, constraints);

            constraints.gridx = 1;
            constraints.gridy = 1;
            constraints.weightx = 1.0;
            constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            add(textLabel2, constraints);
        }
    }
}
```

Playing with anchors (`constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START`) set radio button and one label to the top, but second label still appears in the center.

How to make panels appear on the top instead of center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the maximum size is by default defined as `Integer.MAX_VALUE` x `Integer.MAX_VALUE` for the newly added `RecordPanel` component causing the maximum available area to be used. This dimension is observed by `BoxLayout`.

You could override `getMaximumSize` in the class `RecordPanel`

```
@Override
public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
   return new Dimension(300, getPreferredSize().height);
}
```

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) has full details on how sizing is achieved using `BoxLayout`

Comment: [BoxLayout doc from oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) provides the informations about the layout honoring the max and min size.

Comment: If you add Border to each GridBagLayout, you'll see that this cell takes all the available space. But if I set specific height, I can make mistake because height might be lower/bigger that 30 in case of big label text (if I correctly understood what you meant).

Comment: Then use the preferred size height as shown in the update...:)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to use MigLayout instead of BoxLayout this might be a solution for you:

First, change your panel layout to MigLayout:

```
panel.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[]", "[]"));
```

Create an static variable for the class to count in which row the new `RecordPanel' element is added to:

```
public class Test extends JFrame {
    static int index = 0;
```

Then replace the `add` to the panel line to:

```
panel.add(new RecordPanel("text1", "text2"), "cell 0 " + index++);
```

This will insert every new `RecordPanel` into a new row, thanks to the `index` always being incremented.

You may want to wrap your panel into a ScrollView to add a scroll bar when the elements fill the panel.

Answer (score 0):

The element GridBagConstraints.anchor is the right choice but you have to use one of these values GridBagConstraints.NORTH to GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST.

For example `constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH`

Comment: In my opinion, you need to add a JPanel which fills the full size of the JFrame and insert the GridBagConstraints there.

Comment: Hm, you mean wrap current GridBagLayout with Jpanel (with, e.g. FlowLayout) and wrap it then with another GridBagLayout?